# How to Configure Client Authentication with Beam KafkaIO

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam

I have been going through the Beam KafkaIO tutorials and have been trying to find documentation on kafka client authentication, but so far only found very basic examples. I need to provide the following configuration for the Kafkaio client to successful authenticate:

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka1:9093
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
```

How would I specify this configuration?

So far, all I have found in examples is to configure in this way:

```
p.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()
.withBootstrapServers("kafka1:9022")
.withTopic("test-topic")
.withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
.withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the ssl configuration using `updateConsumerProperties(properties)` method.
 For that you need to set the below consumer properties.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "SSL");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, "/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.truststore.jks");    
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, resourcePath.get("keystore.jks"));
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,  "test1234");
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG,  "test1234"); 
props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG,  "test1234");
```

Pass the above properties in the method as given below :

```
p.apply(KafkaIO.<Long, String>read()
.withBootstrapServers("kafka1:9022")
.withTopic("test-topic")
.withKeyDeserializer(LongDeserializer.class)
.withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
.updateConsumerProperties(props)
```

You can find more documentation here about how to set the custom properties in KafkaIO : https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.html